# Oracle style dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, reporting-services

We have an SSRS report on which we want to show a date field in the following format `DD-MMM-YY` like in Oracle. That converts dates to `25-Jan-11`

So in the SQL that does the final select, we use `Replace (CONVERT (VarChar, DateTimeColumn,106), ' ', '-')`

Is there a better way of doing this conversion?

Answer (score 2):

#### Within SQL Server

SQL Server CONVERT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

No, that specific format is not available so what you are doing is what there is.  I normally prefer to size varchar columns instead of leaving it unsized.

I also notice you have 106, which is DD-MMM-YYYY not DD-MMM-YY.  Did you mean to use 6?

```
REPLACE(CONVERT (varchar(9), DateTimeColumn, 6), ' ', '-')
```

#### Using SSRS formatting

```
=Format(Fields!DateTimeColumn.Value, “dd-MMM-yy”)
```

Comment: Yes, personally I'd bring the value back from SQL Server as a datetime and then format it in the report. You don't even need to use an explicit expression -- just set the "Format" property of the cell to `dd-MMM-yy` in the Properties pane.